# Android: How to create layouts for 1080x1920 Resolution in Eclipse and preview the same

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to design layouts for **1080x1920** resolution(Galaxy S4) but I am not able to find any option to **preview the XML** in the Eclipse and no supporting resolution's emulator is there in the AVD Manager. **[image: emulator]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AVD, you have a tab "device definitions". Click on "New" ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Virtual device manager(AVD) Click "Device Definition". From that click new devices. You have option to add new devices. Follow screenshots
[image: Create new Device]

[image: Device definitions]